# React Native change Redux state in seperate method file

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, store

We recently switched over to Redux in our React Native app. I'm currently trying to build in a custom popup if an API call fails (either a bug or a timeout) to let the user know that something happened. This is done by rendering a second Modal component in the App.js (inside the reducer) that pops up based on a Redux state by drawing it over the app component itself.

App.js render:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <LoginNavigation />
  <ENoConnectionModal/>
</provider>
```

The modal keeps its own visibility state based on the redux state.

redux usage in modal:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  Console.logObject(state);
  const { showNoConnectionModal } = state.connectionReducer;
  return { showNoConnectionModal };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => // this is used by the modal to close (dismiss) itself
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      changeConnectionModalStatus,
    },
    dispatch
  );

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ENoConnectionModal);
```

Modal visibility:

```
isVisible={this.props.showNoConnectionModal}
```

Connection reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  showNoConnectionModal: false, // set to true if call fails
};

const connectionReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_CONNECTION_MODAL:
      return { ...state, showNoConnectionModal: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default connectionReducer;
```

Connection action:

```
export const changeConnectionModalStatus = showNoConnectionModal => ({
  type: TOGGLE_CONNECTION_MODAL,
  payload: showNoConnectionModal,
});
```

The `showNoConnectionModal` state should be set to true may any API call fail. The flow of making an API call is as follows:

A page (component) needs data from an API. The component calles a method of a certain file, E.G. `userApi.loginUser()`. This basically sets up the headers and such. `userApi.loginUser()` calls one of four methods of a file called BaseRequest (methods being get(), post(), put() and pop()). The baserequest is nothing more than a single method that is called by one of four methods to send an API call using a certain fetch method to a certain API location. An oversimplified version of the `baseRequest` main request method would be

```
//target is API url, endpoint is specific call, options is options in fetch request.
async function request(target, endpoint, request) {
  // Execute fetch, store result in let "result".
  if (result.status !== 200 && result.status !== 201) {
    const throwing = `URL called:\n${requestEndpoint}\nCall failed! Status: ${result.status}\ncontent: ${content}`

    ---set redux state to false---
    return throwing;
  }
  const content = result.json();
  return content
}
```

How would I set the redux state in the baseRequest? I don't want to build in a check on every single page, if possible.

**EDIT**: The flow is as follows:
Component invokes method in any API file (E.G. API file being `userAPI`, method being 'loginUser). loginUser simply sets up the API target (url), endpoint (E.G. `"/loginUser/...."`) and calls baseRequest's post. Post sets the method and body of the fetch request. Post invokes the request method which makes the request (see above). 
In short: `component -> userApi.loginUser() -> baseRequest.post() -> baseRequest.request()`.

The page stores the data of the API in a local state, not Redux.

A chain like this happens with every API call (but with different API calls). Whenever any call fails, the redux state should be updated, preferably in baseRequest so I don't have to build in the check 20+ times (on each page / component).

Comment: You shouldn't use async actions directly with redux because you will experience side-effects - you should pick some middleware like redux-observable /redux-saga /redux-thunk. Then you call an action, middleware send request, recieves response and according to it sends action to reducer to change data.

Comment: The reason why I haven't tried using a middleware yet is because the data returned from the API call won't be stored in the redux state, rather a local one. The only time where the redux state is altered is if the API call is not successful. So do I still modify the reducer here?

Comment: Well... without middleware rule is the same, in request callback just dispatch an action or use setState.

Comment: I tried it via importing the store in baseRequest but it was giving an error (import cycle). turns out that's completely unrelated (which needs to be fixed with a middleware, lol). I don't know if this is what you meant but it seems to be working fine.

Comment: `importing the store in baseRequest` why did you do that? Let's say you have method inside your component - fetchFriendsList - so you do there typical request and on success call mapped to props dispatch (let's call it setFriendsList - so you just call this.props.sendFriendsList() on success - dispatch dispatches an action, action is processed by your reducer, reducer changes state, state changes view.

Comment: Because the data recieved itself doesn't need to be in the Redux state. The page invokes the API call and stores the received data. The only think that would need to be updated is the state of the modal. The modal needs to pop up on every API call. I thought the best way would be to have the baserequest tell the Redux state that the call failed. From what I'm gettin from your method is to have a check in every single API call, which is something I want to avoid. (I have to go now, i'll check back in a few hours or tomorrow, sorry).

Comment: I added some extra info in the post itself. Hopefully that clears up a bit. Also, with `From what I'm gettin from your method is to have a check in every single API call, which is something I want to avoid` I meant a check on every single page.